# How to remove multiple lines (block of code) in multiple files in JS?

Tags: javascript, nft

I am using Hashlips code for generating NFTs (10 000 NFTs), however, I have added data for Solana, which I've decided not go with and I would like to remove it. The code of block is in every single NFT, it would take a lot of time to delete manually.

The files are in json folder and the same code is:

```
"properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "image.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Which properties are you trying to remove? And, I assume this is part of an array of objects? We'll need to see an example of the complete structure (It doesn't have to include all of the objects, just all of the relevant structure with fake data if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node.js to read files or directories of file ([documentation of file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)).

Then, using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can create an object with filtered data.

Finally, you can rewrite on each files those new objects.

It can look like this:

```js
import { readdir, readFile, writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

try {
  const files = await readdir('./jsons');
  for (const file of files) {
    const fileContent = await readfile(`./jsons/${file}`, {encoding: 'UTF-8'};
    const json = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    // Do magic
    writeFile(`./jsons/${file}`, json, {encoding: 'UTF-8'})
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Consider saving your files somewhere else before executing your script.